# How manage web applications(PHP) credential in live server?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, server, credentials

I have a Laravel Web application in Github repository. There are three branches such as **master, preview, develop**. When I setup my applications on different environment *(Different server as Live, Preview and Develop staging)*, I want to manage my applications credentials like database credentials, API auth credentials,... etc.

My Laravel applications *.env* file is not including in Github repository. It's good for hide live credentials from developers and others. But I don't like to add separate *.env* file on server level without any tracking of that .env file. Is there any method to **track only *.env* files** with anther private repository and pull it to server level?

So what is the proper way to manage such kind of credentials?

Comment: So basicly, you want versioning for the credentials in `.env`? Why?

Comment: Could you use a Git submodule? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules I personally wouldn't ever bother but it's an option.

Comment: The reason of not putting `.env` in the repository is not to hide them from developers but because they are a distraction that developers should not be dealing with. If you really need to keep them versioned then, by all means, commit them to the repository. It could even be the same repository as the code or maybe a separate repository your IT team uses.

Comment: Main thing is when migrating application between servers, I want to get it easily. Also automate deployment process at the first time.

Comment: @leonardchallis Is it good idea, But is it best approach? How other people handle these credentials?

Comment: Most people set-up their servers with the `.env` files and then all deployments keep them intact. The `.env` file is part of the server and not the deployment. Since `.env` variables are linked to the environment then there should be no changes needed as long as the environement does not change. If you find youself changing these frequently then you need to wonder whether those values should be in `.env` to begin with

Comment: I only ever commit a `.env.sample` with _all directives_ that I need, with no values. It is up to the developer to provide their own for localhost development. And in the hands of the sysadmin when deploying to real servers.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke It's good. But when I using Docker and Jenkins I don't like to give that responsibility to Sysadmin. It should be automated according to my script. In that case I want to track my .env files. Thank you very much to shearing your experience.